# split comma separated datatable column name into two rows in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

Some values are populated from "DB table" to my "datatable" in C# and My datatable looks like following(only one column I have shown):

```
Name,ID <- This is column name
  A
  B
  C
```

I tried it like following and able to split.But, How can I insert this into another datatable?

```
 foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
 {
      string[] str1 = dc.ColumnName.Split(',');
 }
```

I want to split column name into two; That is, "Name" and "ID" and Make it row in another Datatable using C#.

How can I do it? Please help.

Comment: If you are trying to get column names of the tables in your database you should take a look at sys.columns (it is a system view)

Comment: Could any one please tell me, Why this is rated as -Ve??

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Lambda for that - if possible. Something like:

```
DBTable.Items.ForEach(item => {
   var parts = item.Split(',');
   var dataTableItem = new item(parts[0],parts[1]);
   DataTable.Insert(dataTableItem);
});
```